# Is DataWriter the right solution for ExtJS CRUD?

Tags: extjs

I am asking this because in ExtJS in Action book, Page 442, the author said:

> "at the time of this writing,
>   DataWriterhas some undesirable
>   behaviors such as creating a Record
>   for a Store even if the create action
>   failed in the backend"

Is this still the case with ExtJS 3.3.1? If not, should DataWriter be used instead of our own CRUD code?

Answer (score 0):

That is an interesting quote.  The actions happen in sort of the reverse order.

When a new record is created in the store (a phantom record) and the save method is called on the store, the DataWriter will send information for any phantom records to the create action so that they may be created on the back end.

If the response from the server dictates that there was a failure and the correct record data is not sent back, I do not believe the record will remain in the store.

I believe the DataWriter can be valuable to performing CRUD operations on a store.